# Redirect page using plugin in Magento 2

Tags: redirect, magento-2.1.3, plugin, messages

I'm trying to redirect to my shipping information page to cart page based on a condition how can i do this my plugin file is in this path

> /app/code/Sem/Shipment/Plugin/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php

```
    <?php

namespace Sem\Shipment\Plugin\Checkout\Model;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages;

class ShippingInformationManagement
{

    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $jsonResultFactory;
    protected $_checkout; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session

    ) {
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->jsonResultFactory = $jsonResultFactory;
        $this->_session = $session;
    }

    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation

    )
    {
    $objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
    $connection = $resource->getConnection();
    $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
    $address = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
    $postcode = $address->getData('postcode');
    $result = $this->jsonResultFactory->create();
    $resulta = [];
    $pid='';
    if (count($items) > 0){
        foreach ($items as $item)
            $resulta= $item->getName();
            $pid=$item['product_id'];
            $carttotal=$item['grand_total'];
            $weight=$item['weight'];
         $sql ="SELECT ca.postcode FROM
           mgcb_marketplace_product mp
           JOIN mgcb_marketplace_userdata mu ON mp.seller_id = mu.seller_id
           JOIN mgcb_customer_entity ce ON mu.seller_id = ce.entity_id
           JOIN mgcb_customer_address_entity ca ON ce.entity_id = ca.parent_id
           WHERE(mp.mageproduct_id = '$pid')";
        $qryresult = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
        foreach ($qryresult as $qryresult)  
    {
        $pikup=$qryresult['postcode'];


          //Some code using Api here


       $result = json_decode($respon); 
       foreach($result as $object) {
       $stat = $object->status;
      if($stat=="NO SERVICE AVAILABLE")
      {
         //Here i need to redirect to the cart page from checkout By displaying some message
        throw new StateException(__('Shipping is not available on the provided zipcode.'));
     }
    }
    }   
    }

}
}
```

also i need to print the success and error message in the front end 
[image]

Comment: Your first foreach missing '{'. Lots of error, could you fix itself? Or use phpstorm IDE it may help.

Answer (score 1):

There are no this type of implementation that you redirect only using plugin. Because in js part check following logic.

If through any exception from backend(plugin/php class whatever) It check if response status 401 is redirect to login page otherwise it's print message in same page. [Check Here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/error-processor.js#L16).

So you need to implement custom solution for this.

So you need to overwrite following JS

```
Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js
```

[Check following line](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js#L61) you need to add your customization here.

OR

[Overwrite following JS and customize your own logic](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/error-processor.js#L15)

[Update]

Following sample code display same page error message.

```
namespace Sem\Shipment\Plugin\Checkout\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages;

class ShippingInformationManagement
{
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $jsonResultFactory;
    protected $checkout;
    protected $resource;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->jsonResultFactory = $jsonResultFactory;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation

    ) {
        $connection = $this->resource->getConnection();
        $items = $this->session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        $address = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
        $postcode = $address->getData('postcode');
        $resulta = [];
        $pid='';
        if (count($items) > 0){
            throw new StateException(__('Shipping is not available on the provided zipcode.'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Sohel Rana but hear i'm write this code on plugin if you need i will post the full code

Comment: You cant redirect only using plugin. You must need to customize js too.

Comment: @ Sohel Rana i have updated my full code this one i have used to check the delivery availability using zip code before saving the shipping address i don't know  I'm on the correct direction if you have any sujjection please help me

Comment: Check updated answer. It may help. You need now js overwrite. Plugin looks good.

Comment: Ok I will try this before that i have tried to disply an error message on screen using state exception but i'm getting "400 bad request in console " why this? why can't i print the message on screen

Comment: Check updated answer.

Comment: Now message showing but still have 400 bad request error and not moving to next step also the message hide after a few seconds

Comment: It's working fine here. Clear cache and remove var/generation/*. Also open browser console. Check what is the error.

Comment: Please replace your whole code by my updated code. Because your code has many error.

Comment: I have used your code and getting this error on my console  
400 Bad Request check the updated question i have added the screen shot

Comment: once more we have discused about redirecting to cart page here i need to know in my code after throwing exception message i have to set the redirection there what i want to do? with that exception how can i through 401 exception if i do like this is it effect any other position